# Hold temporary information in gridview before post-back

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, temp-tables, temporary

I have a Dialog (Modal), where I'll register one (or several) contact.

the contact goes to a gridview, where they may be edited or deleted.

the data in the Gridview, can only be saved in the database at the end of the process.

How can I achieve this?

**Modal code**

```
$(function () {
    $(".ModalBox").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 602,
        modal: true,
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        }
    });
});
```

**OBS.:**

- I don't have a good sample of CSharp or html code, 'cuz i don't know how to achieve this. All my code look messy atm (trying a lot of things already)
- My GridView is an ascx, and the modal is in the same ascx.
- I belive some temporary table, or something like this will help, but i never did something like it (looks like a shop cart software), and i don't even know how look for it.

Thank you. if you can do some code sample, it will be GREAT.

EDIT:
i did this code:

**CSharp code:**

```
[Serializable]
        public class TabelaTempContato
        {
            public int IDCliente { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Telefone { get; set; }
            public string Cpf { get; set; }
            public string Rg { get; set; }
            public string Departamento { get; set; }
            public string Cargo { get; set; }
        }

        protected List ListaTabelaTemp
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["TabelaTemp"] == null)
                {
                    this.ViewState["TabelaTemp"] = new List();
                }

                return (List)this.ViewState["TabelaTemp"];
            }
        }

        protected void AddItem()
        {
            this.ListaTabelaTemp.Add(new TabelaTempContato());
            this.gvContato.DataSource = this.ListaTabelaTemp;
            this.gvContato.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AddItem();
        }
```

i create one temporary gridview, but the data is empty, i tried pull it from my text in the modal, but i was not able to, i'm i'm not familiar in how i'll get the data from gridview to my database. (i believe this is the easier part, then i not focused at it in the moment)

EDIT: I create the answer with my solution.

Comment: I would be very careful about storing your lists in ViewState like that.  It can be a real performance killer - I've made that mistake myself many years ago. Push the values to hidden form field if you need them at Page scope.  Otherwise, a database won't cost you much.

Comment: Thanks Corey =) i understand the problem in save in Viwestate the data. but as the project as right now, it's kind hard to change it right now, so i'm paging (via database query) with a short amount and waiting until my boss let me remake the project (the project start with the prevision of being remake o.O"). But is a GREAT and real advise, thanks again =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        [Serializable]
        public struct TempContato
        {
            public int IDCliente { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Telefone { get; set; }
            public string Cpf { get; set; }
            public string Rg { get; set; }
            public string Departamento { get; set; }
            public string Cargo { get; set; }
        }

        protected List ListaTabelaTemp
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["ListaTempContato"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["ListaTempContato"] = new List();

                return (List)this.ViewState["ListaTempContato"];
            }
        }

        protected void AddItem()
        {
            TempContato tempContato = new TempContato();

            //tempContato.IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtEmailContato.Text);
            tempContato.Nome = this.txtNomeContato.Text;
            tempContato.Email = this.txtEmailContato.Text;
            tempContato.Telefone = this.txtTelefoneContato.Text;
            tempContato.Cpf = this.txtCpfContato.Text;
            tempContato.Rg = this.txtRgContato.Text;
            tempContato.Departamento = this.ddlDepartamentoContato.SelectedValue;
            tempContato.Cargo = this.ddlCargoContato.SelectedValue;

            this.ListaTabelaTemp.Add(tempContato);
        }

        protected void AtualizarGrid()
        {
            this.gvContato.DataSource = this.ListaTabelaTemp;
            this.gvContato.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AddItem();
            this.AtualizarGrid();
        }
```

Now i get the values from my modal! Just need a couple of things now (i belive).

1- Get the data in my database to load the GridView for the first time (if it's an edition), and load with the new temp data.

2- Save the new temp data.

DONE:

1- i load in my viewstate and use it to load the grid.

2- also using my viewstate to save my data, in the database.